# Instrument resolution or Standard Error of the mean

Tags: probability, statistics, experimental-mathematics, standard-error

Say I tried to measure the length of an object with an instrument that has a resolution of of 0.1mm and got the following:

12.5,12.5,12.5,12.5,12.5,12.5,12.5,12.5,
12.5,12.5

(all in mm). The standard error I would get is 0, which would imply that I have found the population mean, which is obviously not true. Even if I replaced one of the values with 12.6 my standard error would still be a lot smaller than the resolution. The question I'm alluding to is how would I conduct my error analysis? I understand how to conduct error analysis with standard errors but I don't know how to do it with the instruments resolution. Would I just say my standard error = 0.1mm and do my usual error analysis??

Comment: Hard to be very precise...you could just add a noise term to the measure...make it $12.5$ plus some small noise.  That may well be better than ignoring the possible error, but of course you have to guess at the error term.  Depends on what it is you are trying to compute.

Comment: How big/small would you make the noise? Would the size of the noise be affected by the resolution of the instrument?

Comment: Well, as I understand what you wrote, seeing a reading of $12.5$ means that the true measure is in $[12.45, 12.55]$, right?  So you could simply take a uniform distribution there.  Or you could take a normal which is nearly) supported in that interval (Gaussian noise is a standard assumption in lots of contexts).   Absent other considerations I'd go for simple.

Comment: Do you know the instrument's standard error? If you use Bayes and there's 10 samples (apologies if I miscounted), there's a (k+1)/(n+2) or 11/12 chance that any given reading will yield 12.5 but not sure that helps